# Javascript Validation for a phone number (Numbers, spaces, dots, hyphens)

Tags: javascript, validation

So I have this validation for alphanumeric's `(/^[A-Za-z0-9,\+-]+$/)` however I want a validation for a phone number which only allows Numbers, Spaces, Dots and Hyphens.  What code would I use to check for those.

Thanks
Ben

Comment: Do you want it to accept any string of numbers, spaces, dots, and hyphens? Or only valid phone numbers? What about parentheses, which people often put around the area code?

Comment: According to my specifications its just Numbers, Spaces, Dots and Hyphens only.  Thats any order and any length

Comment: /^[0-9\s\.-]+$/ But honestly I think validating a phone number is impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to my specifications its just Numbers, Spaces, Dots and Hyphens only. Thats any order and any length

That would be:

```
/^[0-9 \.-]+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html),

```
/^[\d\s\.\-]+$/
```

`\d` is numbers, `\s` is whitespace, `\.` is dots, `\-` is hyphens.
The `+` means "one or more" characters within `[` and `]`, and `^` and `$` match the start and end of the string, respectively.

If your phone number starts with a country code, you may also want a plus sign as the first non-whitespace character

```
/^(?:\s*\+)?[\d\s\.\-]+$/
```

Here, the `(?:`..`)` means "don't create a reference for this group", `*` means zero or more of previous character, `\+` is a plus sign and the `(`..`)?` means "this group is optional".

Comment: I don't think you need to escape special characters inside `[]`, though it certainly doesn't hurt. I'm talking about `.` and `-` (while not between other characters). This will also work: `/^[\d\s.-]+$/`

Comment: @Zecc, True, however I always escape them because it's clearer if you're using lots in and out of brackets as the usage is "more standard".

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with this while working on a similar problem.
This should solve most US and International numbers.

```
/(?<optional>[+])?(?:(?<countryCode>\d)[.-]?)?[\s]?\(?(?<areaCodes>\d{3})\)?[.-]?[\s]?(?<codeOne>\d{3})[.-]?[\s]?(?<codeTwo>\d{4,})/g
```

As you can see the + in the front is *optional*, *countryCode* is optional and can be followed by,***. -*** or space, *areaCode* is mandatory and it has to match exactly three digits followed by the remaining number.